# Why WolframAlpha solves this, but Mathematica can't?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a system of equations using Mathematica, to which it returns

> { }

which I understand might be due to the fact that there are many variables than equations. To check this, I entered this

```
Solve[{xy + yz + zx == 1, xy + x^2 + y^2 == 3}, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

which again returned `{ }`. Now of course in this case we have many solutions, so my guess seems right. However, when I try the 
[same thing in WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(xy+%2B+yz+%2B+zx+%3D+1)+and+(xy+%2B+x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%3D+3)+for+x,y,z), it returns an answer.

So my question is: what can I do to ensure that Mathematica returns an answer to this question. In general, since I am solving a large systems of equations, what should be my general strategy to get some answer from Mathematica.

Comment: `xy` is a symbol named "xy". To multiply `x` and `y` you need to insert a space or * between them.

Comment: W|A "guesses" that `xy` is intended to be `x*y`. Lucky guess. Actual programming languages, which have stated rules of syntax, cannot do that.

Comment: Thank you @SimonWoods and DanielLichtblau for the comments. That's interesting since I thought that Mathematica is similar to WolframAlpha and I never bothered to make that distinction in WolframAlpha.

Comment: actually alpha doesnt seem to ever treat multiple characters together as a single symbol, always a product unless it spells something

Comment: I concur and also vote to close this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper syntax is

```
Solve[{x*y + y*z + z*x == 1, x*y + x^2 + y^2 == 3}, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

or with spaces instead of `*`. The result is a solution given by means of `Root` objects. One can use `ToRadicals`, which

> attempts to express all `Root` objects in expr in terms of radicals.

```
ToRadicals @ Solve[{x*y + y*z + z*x == 1, x*y + x^2 + y^2 == 3}, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

The result is given by `ConditionalExpression`s, which basically mean that the first two solutions are valid when $z\neq 0$. To get rid of the `ConditionalExpression`s, use `Normal`:

```
Normal @ ToRadicals @
   Solve[{x*y + y*z + z*x == 1, x*y + x^2 + y^2 == 3}, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

And finally, run `FullSimplify` to get a more transparent output:

```
FullSimplify @ Normal @ ToRadicals @
   Solve[{x*y + y*z + z*x == 1, x*y + x^2 + y^2 == 3}, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

[image]

Comment: Use `FullSimplify` to get a cleaner form of the result.